# Is there a way to know which elements are a generator in a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$U_7 = {[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]}$

This group with respect to multiplication. I know that $[3]$ is a generator; I verified this using trial and error. I wonder if there is a more systematic way to know if an element is a generator for a group?

Answer (score 1):

If a group has a single generator, then it's cyclic, and the generators of the cyclic group $Z_n$ (written additively) are just the numbers relatively prime to $n$.  Of course, most groups cannot be generated by a single element.

Your group is isomorphic to the integers (mod 6).  The generators of that cyclic group are 1 and 5.  To see how this corresponds to your group, you'd then just need to set up an explicit isomorphism between the additive group of integers (mod 6) and your group.

Comment: yes , but what makes [3] the only generator for U_7 then ?

Comment: It isn't.  Your group is cyclic of order 6, so there are two generators (because there are two numbers between 1 and 5 relatively prime to 6).